# java why different memory usage for primitive versus object array in 2D

Tags: java, memory, multidimensional-array

Relevant code

```
int row = 100000;
int col = 18;

Object[][] objectArray = new Object[row][1];
int[][] intArray = new int[row][1];

System.out.println("Size of objectArray  = " + net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(objectArray) + " bytes");
System.out.println("Size of intArray     = " + net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(intArray) + " bytes");

Object[][] objectMatrix = new Object[row][col];
int[][] intMatrix = new int[row][col];

System.out.println("Size of objectMatrix = " + net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(objectMatrix) + " bytes");
System.out.println("Size of intMatrix    = " + net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(intMatrix) + " bytes");
```

Relevant output

```
Size of objectArray  = 4000024 bytes
Size of intArray     = 4000024 bytes
Size of objectMatrix = 17600024 bytes
Size of intMatrix    = 10400024 bytes
```

If instead of 1D (number of cols=1), I have 2D (number of cols > 1), the object matrix takes more space.

Can someone explain the reason?

Edit: Added another case with just one row

```
    int row = 1;
    int col = 2;

    Object[][] objectArray = new Object[row][1];
    int[][] intArray = new int[row][1];

    System.out.println("Size of objectArray  = " + net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(objectArray) + " bytes");
    System.out.println("Size of intArray     = " + net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(intArray) + " bytes");

    Object[][] objectMatrix = new Object[row][col];
    int[][] intMatrix = new int[row][col];

    System.out.println("Size of objectMatrix = " + net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(objectMatrix) + " bytes");
    System.out.println("Size of intMatrix    = " + net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(intMatrix) + " bytes");
```

Output

```
Size of objectArray  = 64 bytes
Size of intArray     = 64 bytes
Size of objectMatrix = 72 bytes
Size of intMatrix    = 64 bytes
```

Comment: I guess maybe an object array takes more space.  (Dunno why this would be, but it's possible, depending on the internal implementation.)

Comment: (And, of course, on a full 64-bit Java implementation, pointers are twice as big as ints.)

Comment: (I have no idea how deepSizeOf works internally, but if it's somehow looking at allocations there's no guarantee that two identical objects occupy the same size allocations.)

Comment: What are your `SizeOf.skip...` settings?

Comment: net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.skipStaticField(true);

Comment: net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf.skipFlyweightObject(true);

Comment: I am curious to know why the difference between 1D and 2D when you switch from primitive to object?

Comment: It's really weird, because null objects and `int`s should both get a size of 0 with these settings... Do you get similar results with different values for `rows` and `cols`?

Comment: Yes, I added one more case with just one row.

Comment: Either it's a 64-bit JVM or deepSizeOf is making that assumption.  The numbers work out exactly with 64-bit pointers.

Comment: I am using a 64 bit JVM.

Comment: I mentioned that in the second comment.  Why did you not reply sooner?

Comment: Even if pointers are twice as big as int on a 64-bit JVM, why the difference in size? I am still not able to figure out the precise reason.

Comment: @HotLicks Shouldn't `intArray` be smaller than `objectArray` then (1st pair)?

Comment: @trutheality -- Not for an array of 1, since they round to the same block size.

Comment: @HotLicks -- Can you elaborate on your answer? I was wondering that if the size is 1, then something different is going on.

Comment: Object size is rounded to some power of 2, generally either 16 or 32.  So an array of 1 4-byte element and an array of 1 8-byte element are likely to round to the same boundary.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the reference inside of the object array depends on many factors (32 bit vs 64 bit) or if you are in 64 bit are you running compressedOOPs?  Since I typically work in a 64 bit environment I would always expect the Object[] to occupy more memory.  On the other hand an int in Java is defined as a 32bit value, so with an int[] you are going to have 32 bits used for each value plus some overhead for the array object itself.